# Only one root object is allowed by .kv part 2

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I'm using Kivy and i can't seem to understand it. this is my code:

```
// from python
`from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

kv = Builder.load_file('main.py')
# creating the main Screen
class MainScreen(Screen):

    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MyApp(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyApp()
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()`
```

// this is my kv file

```
WindowManager:
   MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: "<Enter_Tasks: >"
```

I just created some simple things inside so i could just see what i just made but ended up receiving this error:

```
 ...
       2:from kivy.app import App
 >>    3:from kivy.lang import Builder
       4:from kivy.properties import StringProperty
       5:from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
 ...
 Only one root object is allowed by .kv
```

Comment: The line `kv = Builder.load_file('main.py')` is loading a python file. It should be a `kv` file.

Comment: geez. I saw that too. Thanks for pointing that out though, I really appreciate it.